# android-How to get rid of big white border around spinner popup

Tags: android

this is an image of my spinner . 
as you can see ,there is a big white border around it . How can I transparent this white border until the black border ?

[image]
thanks you

Answer (score 0):

design your layout containing textView and create custom Adapter for your spinner which inflate your layout  .It will work according to your requirement